# Is it advisible to launch an executable from a webpage

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html, executable, anti-patterns

I have a requirement wherein I need to launch an application (assumed to be installed on the user's machine) from a webpage.

I found that there are several ways of doing so, but I would like to know if this is an acceptable solution. Is it OK to execute applications from a webpage or is this some kind of an anti-pattern?

EDIT: To clarify, I did not mean that the executable will launch on loading the webpage, rather as Florian mentions, it will be on a user click, so the user knows that an executable will be launched. My question was is even this ok?

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea to me. Can you expand on why it's a requirement? It would probably help if you said a bit more about why you're ultimately trying to do.

Comment: I think it's ok but depends on how you launch it. How do you want to launch it then?

Comment: Are you working at Microsoft?

Comment: @Pumbaa80. The answer is no, but I am wondering if the question is a sarcastic one :)

Comment: Yea, I forgot the smiley :) I couldn't help thinking of ActiveX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do this, it is most likely a security flaw. Can you imagine if I run all your applications just because you visited my webpage?

However, you can do something like skype does: adding a protocol that your desktop application handles. This means that when the user will click on the link, it will launch the desktop application handling the protocol.

Skype's links are like this:

```
<a href="skype://username">Skype me!</a>
```

And the skype program is the default handler of the `skype` protocol for your operating system, so it will run it.